# Android RecyclerView inside ViewPager

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to put RecyclerView inside one of ViewPager elements.

But when I try to initialise RecyclerView in MainActivity I get a NullPointerException.

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
```

mRecyclerView is always null.

Can anybody please explain the way how can I put RecyclerView inside ViewPager?

Edit: I'm not using Fragment.

Update: Here is XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryGrey"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:paddingTop="58dp"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you show your xml file?

Comment: Mrugesh, just posted above, thanks

Comment: you should load viewpager with fragments and inside fragment load recyclerview.

Comment: But I'm still lost how can I implement Fragment there. I have three pages for my ViewPager module and have no idea how to use all that in RecyclerView